# Trouble changing UITabBarItem font

Tags: ios, swift, user-interface

I'm trying to set a custom font for a tab bar in iOS 13 and the following almost works, but the font only gets changed once a tab bar item has been selected. Can you let me know what I'm missing please?

```
class MainTabBarController: UITabBarController {
    
    private func setTabBarFont (_ appearance: UITabBarItemAppearance) {
        let myFont = UIFont(name: "Dosis", size: 12)!
        appearance.normal.titleTextAttributes = [NSAttributedString.Key.font: myFont]
        appearance.focused.titleTextAttributes = [NSAttributedString.Key.font: myFont]
        appearance.selected.titleTextAttributes = [NSAttributedString.Key.font: myFont]
        appearance.disabled.titleTextAttributes = [NSAttributedString.Key.font: myFont]
    }
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let appearance = tabBar.standardAppearance
        
        setTabBarFont(appearance.stackedLayoutAppearance)
        setTabBarFont(appearance.inlineLayoutAppearance)
        setTabBarFont(appearance.compactInlineLayoutAppearance)

        self.tabBar.standardAppearance = appearance
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fetch the `items` from `tabBar` and loop through them to set the `titleTextAttributes`, i.e.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    if let items = self.tabBar.items {
        items.forEach {
            $0.setTitleTextAttributes([
                .font: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 10.0, weight: .bold),
                .foregroundColor: UIColor.red
            ], for: .normal)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is that the only way to achieve this? It seems like a rather verbose way of doing it.

Comment: Actually it makes sense now I've had time to play with it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It will work if you change font following way

```
let fontAttributes = [NSAttributedStringKey.font: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 12.0)]
UITabBarItem.appearance().setTitleTextAttributes(fontAttributes, for: .normal)
```

Comment: Thanks - that works for system font, but I'm trying to use a custom font.